# Formatting numbers read from spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, number-formatting

I'm writing a script that creates fixed-width-text output of the contents of a Google Apps Spreadsheet. I retrieve all the values of the current range using the `range.getValues()` method, then I loop through everything a couple times and generate a block of text that looks like a nicely-formatted table when pasted into a fixed-width-font email.

The only issue I'm having is that I cannot replicate the number formatting. I can get the number formatting string using `range.getNumberFormats()`, but I cannot find a method for applying that formatting string within code. I tried using the TEXT (value, format) spreadsheet function, but apparently Google Apps Script does not yet support calling spreadsheet functions from within the JavaScript code itself (see [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&q=26&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Priority%20Component%20Owner&id=26) for proof).

Answer (score 16):

As of [December 2015](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=402#c26), the kludgy work-arounds can be discarded. Google has provided two methods to retrieve the literal string display values from cells. They haven't provided documentation yet, so here's a summary:

**Range.getDisplayValue()**
Returns the display value of the top-left cell in the range, as a String, containing the text value shown on the Sheets UI. Empty cells will return an empty string.

**Range.getDisplayValues()**
Returns the rectangular grid of display values for this range. Returns a two-dimensional array of Strings, indexed by row, then by column. Empty cells will be represented by an empty string in the array. Remember that while a range index starts at 1, 1, the JavaScript array will be indexed from [0][0].

#### Example:

Say we have a range in a spreadsheet that we are interested in, like this:

[image: screenshot]

Those four cells include two of the trickiest formats to work around; date/time and scientific notation. But with the new methods, there's nothing to it.

```js
function demoDisplayValue() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:B2");

  Logger.log( range.getDisplayValue() );
  Logger.log( range.getDisplayValues() );
}
```

#### Log:

```
[16-01-14 13:04:15:864 EST] 1/14/2016 0:00:00
[16-01-14 13:04:15:865 EST] [[1/14/2016 0:00:00, 5.13123E+35], [$3.53, 1,123 lb]]
```

Answer (score 10):

I found a JavaScript method for setting the number of digits after the decimal point called toFixed().

Here's the documentation:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

```
num.toFixed(x) //where x = the number of digits after the decimal point.
```

My Google Apps script needed to return a message with a dollar value pulled from my spreadsheet.  It looked terrible with 10 digits after the decimal point.  This method applied to my variable solved the problem.  I just added a $ in the text portion of the label.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

The list of pre-supplied formats is [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?p=drive_custom_numbers&rd=1). For some formats, a javascript equivalent is relatively straight-forward. For others, it's extremely difficult. And handling user-defined custom formats - good luck with that.

Here's a screenshot showing cell content that has been replicated as html - not fixed, as you are doing, yet using the formats from the spreadsheet.

[image: Screenshot]

There are Google Apps Script helper functions that make it easier, [`Utilities.formatString()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatString(template,%20args)) and [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)).

For dates & times, like `"h:mm:ss am/pm"`, the spreadsheet formats are almost what is needed for the utility - I've found that you just need to tweak the am/pm designation for some formats:

```
  var format = cell.getNumberFormat();
  var jsFormat = format.replace('am/pm','a');
  var jsDate = Utilities.formatDate(
          date,
          this.tzone,
          jsFormat);
```

For dollars, e.g. `"\"$\"#,##0.00"`:

```
  var dollars = Utilities.formatString("$%.2f", num);
```

For percent-formatted numbers, e.g. `"0.00%"`:

```
  var matches = format.match(/\.(0*?)%/);
  var fract = matches ? matches[1].length : 0;     // Fractional part
  var percent = Utilities.formatString("%.Xf%".replace('X',String(fract)), 100*num);
```

For exponentials, like `"0.000E+00"`, utilize the javascript built-in [`toExponential()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential), and tweak the output to look more like the spreadsheet:

```
if (format.indexOf('E') !== -1) {
  var fract = format.match(/\.(0*?)E/)[1].length;  // Fractional part
  return num.toExponential(fract).replace('e','E');
}
```

You can just do a string comparison against the stored spreadsheet formats to pick the right converter.

And what do I mean by extremely difficult? Try to get a formatter that comes up with the exact same numerator and denominator choices Sheets makes for `# ?/?` and `# ??/??`! In the spreadsheet, it's a matter of formatting - in a script, it's much more...

Answer (score 4):

Try the following google apps script

```
function NumberFormat()
{var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var cell = sheet.getRange("A1:B10");
 // Always show 2 decimal points
 cell.setNumberFormat("0,00,000.00");
}
```