# Format a number with many decimal places as currency

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, currency-formatting

I have this script that sends an email with a specific value of a cell in a spreadsheet.

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var column = spr.getRange('k2');
  var values = column.getValues();
  var cell = sheet.getRange('k2');
  cell.setNumberFormat("$0.00");
  var range_bill_com = sheet.getRange('k2');
  if (range_bill_com.getValue() !=-1){
     var recipients = "email@gmail.com";
     var message = '';
     var subject = 'exemplo';
     var body = 'O valor previsto de Lucro/Prejuízo para hoje é de:' + values;
     MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
        }
  };
```

But in the email received, the format of this value is not the same as I would like , that would be in US dollars (ex: "O valor previsto de Lucro/Prejuízopara hoje é de:945.2709034832405).
I tried some changes , but do not know how to get the message value in the format I want.
Can anyone help me change this script?

Comment: You are getting the active spreadsheet twice, with two different variables, no need to duplicate.  Reuse the first one.

Comment: You don't need to use `getValues()` if the range is a single cell. Use `getValue()`  (No "s" on the end).  It only gets a single value.  And it's a one dimensional array, not a two dimensional array.  `getValues()` ("s" on the end) gets a two dimensional array.

Comment: Here is a stackoverflow post that may help: [Formatting numbers from spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25229213/2946873)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First trim the number of decimal places, then concatenate text with a leading dollar sign.

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();

  var column = ss.getRange('k2');
  var value = column.getValue();
  var cell = sheet.getRange('k2');
  cell.setNumberFormat("$0.00");

  var range_bill_com = sheet.getRange('k2');

  if (range_bill_com.getValue() !=-1){
    var recipients = "email@gmail.com";
    var message = '';
    var subject = 'exemplo';
    var valueFormatedAsCurrency = formatToCurrency(value);
    var body = 'O valor previsto de Lucro/Prejuízo para hoje é de:' + 
      valueFormatedAsCurrency;
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
};

function formatToCurrency(inputArg) {
  //Logger.log('typeof inputArg: ' + typeof inputArg);

  var inputToNumber = Number(inputArg);
  var fixedValue = inputToNumber.toFixed(2);

  var valAsString = fixedValue.toString();
  //Logger.log('typeof valAsString: ' + typeof valAsString);

  var valAsCurrency = "$" + valAsString;

  //Logger.log('valAsCurrency: ' + valAsCurrency);
  return valAsCurrency;
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry, Sandy, but in what sequence I put the formatToCurrency function in my script? I have no experience in it. Besides, the value of K2 cell is constantly changing.

Comment: Hááá! It's perfect! I just change "var body" para "var body = 'O valor previsto de Lucro/Prejuízo para hoje é de:' + valueFormatedAsCurrency", and the email works just perfect!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please mark answer as correct.  Thanks for the feedback.  I changed the variable name.